# Accessing parent view's properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Mates, i'm tryin' to acces properties of a backbone view from a sub-view (don't know if is the correct denomination).
Anyway, here's some of the code:

```
App.Views.ViewEditGuest = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#main-content .container_12',
    totalPayments: 0,
    totalBought: 0,

    template: _.template( App.Templates.ViewEditGuest ),

    events: {
        'click #sell' : 'sell'
    },

    sell: Backbone.View.extend({
         el: '#consumos',
         template: _.template( App.Templates.VEGConsumos ),

         render: function(){
                 // I need to acces ViewEditGuest's totalPayments and
                 // totalBought
                 this.$el.html( this.template() );
                 return this;
          }
    }),

    render: function(){
          this.$el.html( this.template(  ) );
          return this;
    }
});
```

So, I need to access ViewEditGuest's totalPayments and totalBought from sell's render method.
I've been looking arround but couldn't find any solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the *correct* way is to stash the data in a model, and then listen to the events when the attributes are updated in both views.

but to answer the question with as little change to the code as possible,

```
sell: Backbone.View.extend({
    parentView: this,
    el: '#consumos',
    template: _.template( App.Templates.VEGConsumos ),
    render: function(){
        console.log( options.parentView.totalBought );
        this.$el.html( this.template() );
        return this;
      }
```

Comment: I've tried that, but doesn't work.
It returns me that options is undefined. I've tried this.parentView, but it returns me all window object.
Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why? Because the `this` will be the context when the classes are defined, ie, the `window` object (I'll assume), and it'll be stored in the prototype. It won't be the parentView.

Comment: .bind() your methods accordingly, or copy the this out to a variable.